# Displaying specific select option based on user's gender

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am trying to set restrictions on `select option` based on their gender and displayed accordingly in the form. Am I allowed to write in this way to compare it with `if else` statement in the form? The output result only shows the first `select option` and not others, regardless their gender.

Here is my code:

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staffQuery)) {
    $sex = $row['gender'];
  ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type of leave </label>        
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <?php
                 if ($sex == "male") {?>
                    <select class="form-control" id="select" name="leave_option">
                       <option value="1">Annual Leave</option>
                       <option value="2">Sick Leave</option>
                       <option value="3">No Pay Leave</option>
                       <option value="4" disabled>Maternity Leave</option>
                       <option value="5">Adoption Leave</option>
                       <option value="6">Childcare Leave</option>
                       <option value="7">Paternity Leave</option>
                       <option value="8">Shared Parental Leave</option>
                       <option value="9">Infant Care Leave</option>
                       <option value="10">Reservist Leave</option>
                   </select>
                   <?php
                   }else {?>
                   <select class="form-control" id="select" name="leave_option">
                       <option value="1">Annual Leave</option>
                       <option value="2">Sick Leave</option>
                       <option value="3">No Pay Leave</option>
                       <option value="4">Maternity Leave</option>
                       <option value="5">Adoption Leave</option>
                       <option value="6">Childcare Leave</option>
                       <option value="7">Paternity Leave</option>
                       <option value="8">Shared Parental Leave</option>
                       <option value="9">Infant Care Leave</option>
                       <option value="10" disabled>Reservist Leave</option>
                   </select>
                   <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
           <?php  } ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve in one condition only, like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" name="leave_option">
      <option value="1">Annual Leave</option>
      <option value="2">Sick Leave</option>
      <option value="3">No Pay Leave</option>
      <option value="4" <?php if($sex == "male") echo "disabled"; ?>>Maternity Leave</option>
      <option value="5">Adoption Leave</option>
      <option value="6">Childcare Leave</option>
      <option value="7">Paternity Leave</option>
      <option value="8">Shared Parental Leave</option>
      <option value="9">Infant Care Leave</option>
      <option value="10" <?php if($sex != "male") echo "disabled"; ?> >Reservist Leave</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Had posted my answer why it didn't work expected. A small blunder on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use if else but it can be more efficient if you write in this way

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staffQuery)) {
    $sex = $row['gender'];
  ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type of leave </label>        
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select" name="leave_option">
                       <option value="1">Annual Leave</option>
                       <option value="2">Sick Leave</option>
                       <option value="3">No Pay Leave</option>
                       <option value="4" <?php echo $sex=="male"?"disabled":"" ?> >Maternity Leave</option>
                       <option value="5">Adoption Leave</option>
                       <option value="6">Childcare Leave</option>
                       <option value="7">Paternity Leave</option>
                       <option value="8">Shared Parental Leave</option>
                       <option value="9">Infant Care Leave</option>
                       <option value="10" <?php echo $sex=="male"?"":"disabled"?>>Reservist Leave</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the desired option then follow this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" name="leave_option">
      <option value="1">Annual Leave</option>
      <option value="2">Sick Leave</option>
      <option value="3">No Pay Leave</option>
      <?php if($sex == "female"){ ?>
      <option value="4">Maternity Leave</option>
      <? } ?>
      <option value="5">Adoption Leave</option>
      <option value="6">Childcare Leave</option>
      <option value="7">Paternity Leave</option>
      <option value="8">Shared Parental Leave</option>
      <option value="9">Infant Care Leave</option>
      <?php if($sex == "male"){ ?>
      <option value="10">Reservist Leave</option>
      <? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Not totally wrong but I am looking to disable the option and not remove it since these leave is actually stated in government website.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why it couldn't work as I have forgotten to retrieve 
`staff_id` from `$_SESSION`, thus the comparison is not working. Glad to fix it and able to do it in more efficient way.Thanks for all your input.

```
$getId = $_SESSION['staff_id']; //missing, thus unable to compare
$staffQuery = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE staff_id = '$getId'";
```